# Donde iniciar la conexión a la MongoDB en express?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, base-de-datos, express

estoy realizando una simple web app, y en la parte de implementación de mongo (usando el modulo **mongoJS**) me surgió la siguiente duda...

***Donde es el lugar MAS apropiado para el inicio de la conexión a la base de datos ?***

En el app.js (y luego lo paso por req.db) o hago la conexion directamente en mi endpoint (que seria donde recibo de mi api los datos a manejar ?? 
tengo dividido de la siguiente forma:

app.js---->api<---->DB

```
//app.js
var mongojs = require('mongojs'); ////<<<<aqui>>>///
var db = mongojs('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb', ['users','games']);


//api.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var userCtrl = require('../controllers/myapp.js');

router.route('/users')

.post(function(req, res, next){  // Agregar user
    userCtrl.createUser(req.body, function(err, status){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.send('usuario guardado');
    }); 
})
module.exports = router;


//myapp.js

var mongojs = require('mongojs'); ////<<<< o aqui?>>>///
var db = mongojs('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb', ['users','games']);


exports.createUser = function (data, cb){
  db.users.insert({
    username:   data.username,
    email:      data.email,
    pass:       data.pass,
    about:      data.about
    }, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    cb(null, true);
  });
};
```

Gracias!

Comment: Como comenta @kiramishima, lo recomendable (como en muchos otros lenguajes) seria crear otro modulo, para que puedas reutilizarlo en otras clases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chale sigo sin poder comentar en SO en español jaja pero en fin, lo recomendable seria que fuera desde otro modulo, no se por ejemplo db.js y en ese exportes la conexión.

En mi caso yo uso mucho mongoose con express y ES6 con Babel y en un archivo dentro de lib/db.js tengo esto:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

mongoose.connect('<mongo-uri>')

export default mongoose
```

Así solo mando a llamarlo en mis modelos sin tener que declararlo varias veces, ejemplo:

```
import db from '../lib/db'
import { Schema } from 'mongoose'
import { v4 } from 'node-uuid'
import mongooseHidden from 'mongoose-hidden'
import _ from 'lodash'

let UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    password: { type: String, hide: true },
    apiKey: { type: String, hide: true },
    apiToken: { type: String, hide: true }
})

UserSchema.plugin(mongooseHidden())

UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if (!this.apiKey) {this.apiKey = v4()}
    if (!this.apiToken) {this.apiToken = v4()}

    next()
})

UserSchema.methods.toPrivateObject = function () {
    let doc = _.extend({}, this._doc)

    delete doc.__v
    delete doc.password

    return doc
}

let User = db.model('User', UserSchema)

export default User
```

En tu caso seria algo así:

```
// db.js
var mongojs = require('mongojs'); ////<<<< o aqui?>>>///
var db = mongojs('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb', ['users','games']);
module.exports = {
  db: db
}
```

Así solo llamas a la conexion

```
var db = require('lib/db').db;

exports.createUser = function (data, cb){
  db.users.insert({
    username:   data.username,
    email:      data.email,
    pass:       data.pass,
    about:      data.about
    }, 
    function(err, data){
      if (err) {
          throw err;
      }
      cb(null, true);
    });
};
```

Saludos

Comment: Como comentas, lo recomendable (como en muchos otros lenguajes) seria crear otro modulo, para que puedas reutilizarlo en otras clases.  a ver si ya puede comentar, decir "Chale" es cool! , saludos.

Comment: jajaja yeah !!!! ya puedo comentar :D, creo que últimamente se me ha pegado eso de decir chale, pero si siempre es recomendable meter la conexion en otro modulo, en muchos getting starteds de express y koa dejan caer la conexion  en el archivo principal junto con los modelos, al final llega a ser horrible ver un archivo de muchas lineas

Comment: Si, termine creando un archivo propio de configuración config.js , e ir exportando desde ahi tanto el objeto db , como otras configuraciones , muchas gracias por la ayuda